# importing opencv4nodejs to React App.js throws TypeError

Tags: node.js, reactjs, opencv, import, peer-dependencies

I'm trying to use opencv4nodejs module in my React app.

Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with 12 CPUs

I had a seemingly successful auto build when I installed in my app directory

`npm install --save opencv4nodejs`

The opencv modules was indeed added to my node_modules folder and "opencv4nodejs" was correctly added to my package.json file as a dependency in my React app (created using create-react-app@3.0.1)

However, if I try to import the module into my App.js file, a TypeError is thrown.

`import cv from "opencv4nodejs";`

The whole Error output is attached [TypeErrorOpenCV.txt](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs/files/3586873/TypeErrorOpenCV.txt)

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_handle' of undefined


(anonymous function)
  1 | module.exports = function (blocking) {
  2 |   [process.stdout, process.stderr].forEach(function (stream) {
> 3 |     if (stream._handle && stream.isTTY && typeof stream._handle.setBlocking === 'function') {
  4 |       stream._handle.setBlocking(blocking);
  5 |     }
  6 |   });
```

The complete terminal output of the autobuild file is 
[opencvAutoBuildTerminalOutput.txt](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs/files/3586884/opencvAutoBuildTerminalOutput.txt) and 
[moreAutoBuildOpenCVtermoutput.txt](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs/files/3586886/moreAutoBuildOpenCVtermoutput.txt)

here are the ending WARN lines during Autobuild completion.

```
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.14.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.1.2 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.0.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.0.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

I tried unsuccessfully to install the peer dependencies myself by adding these to the dependencies in package.json, but this created problems esp with eslint since there actually is an eslint installed, but somehow was not recognized. Are the missing peer dependencies causing my error?

Here are lines that contained the string "Fail" from the AutoBuild output.

```
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_ABSOLUTE_VALUE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_TAUTOLOGICAL_UNDEFINED_COMPARE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHORTEN_64_TO_32 - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ENUM_COMPARE_SWITCH - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INCONSISTENT_MISSING_OVERRIDE - Failed
-- Failed to find installed gflags CMake configuration, searching for gflags build directories exported with CMake.
-- Failed to find gflags - Failed to find an installed/exported CMake configuration for gflags, will perform search for installed gflags components.
-- Failed to find gflags - Could not find gflags include directory, set GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing gflags/gflags.h
-- Failed to find glog - Could not find glog include directory, set GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing glog/logging.h
```

Here are the lines of Autobuild that contained "not found"

```
-- Looking for ccache - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- Module opencv_ovis disabled because OGRE3D was not found
-- Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Glog/Gflags
```

and here is general info from the AutoBuild

```
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.4.6 =====================================
--   Version control:               3.4.6
--
--   Extra modules:
--     Location (extra):            /home/nicole/Documents/sdspage/canvas-app/node_modules/opencv-build/opencv/opencv_contrib/modules
--     Version control (extra):     3.4.6
--
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2019-09-07T17:27:04Z
--     Host:                        Linux 5.0.0-27-generic x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.10.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               Release
--
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
--       requested:                 SSE3
--     Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       SSE4_1 (12 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
--       SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
--       FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
--       AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
--       AVX2 (26 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
--       AVX512_SKX (2 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_SKX
--
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++11:                       YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 7.4.0)
```

Comment: Hi, I have send you the proposal at upwork, let discuss there.

Comment: can you post your dependecies, dev too from package.json

Comment: Also judging from source code of  `opencv4nodejs` it is not meant for browser,but rather for node or electron apps

Comment: Yes, you both nailed it on the head - nodecv4nodejs is meant for server side. Create-react-app is only browser. Thank you for your help, I'm going to make a backend with nodejs.